# rsyncの -r と -R オプションの違いがわかりません

Tags: rsync

rsyncでコピー元のディレクトリ構成をそのままコピー先にコピーするオプションを調べた際、例として、以下のコマンドを実行しました。

```
rsync -rhvt /var/log/wtmp test@example.com:/home/test/
```

上記のようなコマンドでコピーすると、「/home/test/」の下に wtmp のみがコピーされます。

そのため色々調べて `-r` を `-R` に変えると以下のようにコピー元のディレクトリ構成をそのままコピーすることができました。

```
/home/test/var/log/wtmp
```

しかしここで1点疑問なのですが、`-r` オプションは「再帰的にコピーする」オプションなので、指定したコピー元のディレクト構造がそのままコピー先にコピーされると思いました。
また、`-R` のオプションも「相対パス名を使用する」と書かれていてイマイチオプションの意味がわかりません。

`-r` と `-R` のそれぞれの意味、違いを教えていただけると幸いです。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`--recursive`, `-r`](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.1#opt--recursive)は指定されたパスがディレクトリの場合に再帰的にコピーします。`/var/log/wtmp`はファイルなので再帰的には動作せず１ファイルのコピーとなります。

[`--relative`, `-R`](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.1#opt--relative)は指定されたパスを相対ディレクトリとして扱います。

```
rsync -R /var/log/wtmp ...
```

と指定した場合、

```
(cd /; rsync -R var/log/wtmp ...)
```

と解釈され、`var/log/wtmp`としてコピーされます。

なお

```
rsync -R /var/./log/wtmp ...
```

と`./`を挟んだ場合、

```
(cd /var; rsync -R log/wtmp ...)
```

と解釈され、`./`以降、つまり`log/wtmp`としてコピーされます。